# Expectation of linearity for expected number of die rolls.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, expectation

I'm trying to understand how linearty of expectation works and I've come accross [this example](https://brilliant.org/wiki/expected-value/#linearity-of-expectation-basic) on an article on brilliant.org.

Right after they state the theorem on the linearity of expectation. There is an example, and I don't really understand it at all.

I understand why there is a 1/6th probability that the next roll is a 6, and a 5/6th probability that the next roll will produce a number other than 6. But how did they arrive at the following

> $X_n$ is the random variable that represents the number of rolls
>   required to get $n$ consecutive sixes.
>
> In order to get $n$ consecutive sixes, there must first be $n-1$
>   consecutive sixes. Then, the $n^{th}$ consecutive six will occur on
>   the next roll with $1/6$ probability, or the process will start over
>   on the next roll with $5/6$ probability.
>
> $$\text{E}[X_n]=\text{E}\left[\dfrac{1}{6}\left(X_{n-1}+1\right)+\dfrac{5}{6}\left(X_{n-1}+1+X_n\right)\right]=\text{E}\left[X_{n-1}+1+\dfrac{5}{6}X_n\right]$$

Comment: What is $X_n$??

Comment: I suggest you copy and paste in the details from the example rather that posting a link and asking us to follow it.

Comment: The paragraph just before the computation is a good starting (and ending?) point